# Does PyODBC Trusted Connection Work When Trying To Build A Web App on Something Like AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyodbc

I am trying to build a web application that will be deployed on AWS. Apart of the backend is creating a SQL server connection. Anytime I use trusted connection, it works, but anytime I try to enter my UID and Password, user authentication fails. Will using trusted connection be a problem when it is time to deploy to AWS?

**USING TRUSTED CONNECTION: **

```
import pandas as pd

import pyodbc

 

str_con = 'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; SERVER=<SERVER_NAME>;DATABASE=<DATABASE_NAME>; Trusted_Connection=yes;'

conn = pyodbc.connect(str_con, autocommit=True)

crsr = conn.cursor()

 

SQL = """ SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM DATABASE_NAME """

 

data = pd.read_sql(

       SQL,

      conn

)
```

**USING UID AND PASSWORD **

```
import pandas as pd

import pyodbc
SERVER = 'SERVER_NAME'
DATABASE = 'DATABASE_NAME'
USERNAME = 'candy_man'
PASSWORD = 'sweet_sugar'

connectionString = f'DRIVER={{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}};SERVER={SERVER};DATABASE={DATABASE};UID={USERNAME};PWD={PASSWORD}'

conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionString, autocommit=True)

crsr = conn.cursor()
```

**The below is the error I am getting when using UID and Password: **

InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'candy_man'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'candy_man'. (18456)")

I was expecting password and UID to work because it apart of the active directory.